# Can I use a list as an attribute when creating a new object?

Tags: python

I've been learning python, and want to get started on my first project, ive finished learning about classes today, and would like to work on my understanding of algorithms, and how everything I've learned can tie together.  I'd like to do this because I feel like these online resources give you good Info, but don't teach much about applying these concepts to projects.

I want to make a simple program, where I can type in a recipe name, and print the ingredients, cook time,  steps, and name.  I'd like to use a list for ingredients, and steps, and I'd like to print those in list format (perhaps wrapped in a border).  Is this possible?

```
Class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, recipe_name, ingredients, cook_time, steps)
        (self.recipe_name = recipe_name)
        (self.ingredients = ingredients)
        (self.cook_time = cook_time)
        (self.steps = steps)

Chicken Noodle = Recipe(Chicken Noodle, [Broth, noodles], 7 minutes, [Bring water to boil, add broth, etc.]
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I make sure it all ends up in the code box?  I format while typing but then that happens.

Comment: Highlight the code you want to box up and hit ctrl+K

Comment: You do not need any parentheses around the assignment statements, but you need a colon at the end of the second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a class to contain one recipe makes sense to me, but I would prefer a class to contain all my recipes:

```
class Recipes:
  def __init__(self):
    self.recipes = {}

  def add_recipes(self, to_add):
      for key in to_add:
          self.recipes[key] = to_add[key]

  def display_recipe(self, name):
    recipe = self.recipes[name]  
    print("Name: ",name)
    print("Ingredients: ", *recipe["ingredients"])
    print("Cook time: ", recipe["cooktime"])

r = Recipes()
r.add_recipes({"Chicken Noodle": {"ingredients": ["Broth", "noodles"], "cooktime": "7 minutes"}})
r.display_recipe("Chicken Noodle")
```

You have some errors in your code:

```
Chicken Noodle = Recipe(Chicken Noodle, [Broth, noodles], 7 minutes, [Bring water to boil, add broth, etc.]
```

Needs to become:

```
ChickenNoodle = Recipe("Chicken Noodle", ["Broth", "noodles"], "7 minutes", ["Bring water to boil", "add broth, etc."])
```

The class definition also needs to change a bit, to conform to conventional style and some syntax rules:

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__ (self, recipe_name, ingredients, cook_time, steps):
        self.recipe_name = recipe_name
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.cook_time = cook_time
        self.steps = steps
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on my syntax errors please?  I keep getting syntax error when I try to run my code, and don't understand why, as it looks identical to every tutorial I've read in my eyes.  I understand the need to put things in string format, I actually did that at first, but wasn't 100% sure so I took it out to see what happens.

Comment: When you get a syntax error it should point you to the line where the error is located @Adag89

Comment: I specifically don't understand what self.recipes{} does, and what r. Is.  I've seen these explained a little in YouTube tutorials, but hasn't been touched on in sololearn.

Comment: It points me to: Class Recipe: with Recipe highlited red, but not explanation.  I think I need to reinstall python, I get lots of weird errors I don't get using other computers.

Comment: `r = Recipes()` instantiates the class, and `self.recipes = {}` makes an empty dictionary that serves as a container where the class methods store and lookup recipes

Comment: Ok thanks so much, I'll do some additional studying on classes, the course I'm taking obviously hasn't covered enough in depth for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty close! You don't need those parens in your constructor method. I removed those. To print out the entire recipe, we can simple use the to string function. Change it as you desire:

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, recipe_name, ingredients, cook_time, steps):
        self.recipe_name = recipe_name
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.cook_time = cook_time
        self.steps = steps


    def __str__(self):
      output = ''
      output += 'Here is the recipe for {}:\n'.format(self.recipe_name)
      output += 'You will need: {}\n'.format(self.ingredients)
      output += 'This recipe takes: {}\n'.format(self.cook_time)
      output += 'Here are the steps involved:\n'

      for i, step in enumerate(self.steps):
        output += 'Step {}: {}\n'.format(i + 1, step)

      return output
```

You can run this:

```
chicken_noodle = Recipe('Chicken Noodle', ['Broth', 'noodles'], '7 minutes', ['Bring water to boil', 'add broth'])

print (chicken_noodle)
```

output:

```
Here is the recipe for Chicken Noodle:
You will need: ['Broth', 'noodles']
This recipe takes: 7 minutes
Here are the steps involved:
Step 1: Bring water to boil
Step 2: add broth
```

Comment: When I execute this code I get an error that says that def __str__ overrides def __init__ method.  Any idea why?

Comment: Hm, tough to tell. Are you running it with other code? Did you copy and past exactly as above and same indentation level?